# Install apk programmatically auto-updating my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, installation

Hi I'm in trouble with this code...
I want to check on my server if versione code of my app is the Latest and update the app or not.

This Is my checkupdate Activity

'''

public class CheckUPD extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView textServer; // text result from server on layout

int versionCodeThis ;// Version code of this app es. 1
String versionNameThis = ""; // Version name of this app es. V0.01
static String versionCodeServer = "";
static String versionCodeThisString;

static boolean versionegiusta = false;

RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_upd);

    textServer = findViewById(R.id.updtxtserver); // text result from server on layout

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);

        versionCodeThis = packageInfo.versionCode; // versionCode of this app es. 1             int
        versionNameThis = packageInfo.versionName; // versionName of this app es. V0.01         String

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.updtxtcurrent)).setText(getString(R.string.currentver) + " " + versionNameThis);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("http://google.com/version.json",null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("app");

                        JSONObject app = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                        String name = app.getString("name");
                        String versionName = app.getString("versionName");
                        String versionCode = app.getString("versionCode");

                        textServer.setText(name+ "\n" + versionName + "\n" + versionCode + "\n");

                        versionCodeThisString = String.valueOf(versionCodeThis);     // transform int versionCodeThis in String versionCodeThisString
                        versionCodeServer= versionCode;     // transform int versionCodeThis in String versionCodeThisString

                        if ( versionCodeThisString.equals(versionCode)    ) {
                            Log.i("codiceversioneonline",versionCode);
                            Log.i("codiceversione",versionCodeThisString);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.usinglatest), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            versionegiusta= true;
                        }
                        else  {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.updateavaillable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley","ERROR");
                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


}

public void download(View view) {
    String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
    String fileName = "latest.apk";
    destination += fileName;
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

    //Delete update file if exists
    File file = new File(destination);
    if (file.exists())
        //file.delete() - test this, I think sometimes it doesnt work
        file.delete();



    //set downloadmanager
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://google.com/latest.apk"));


    //set destination
    request.setDestinationUri(uri);

    // get download service and enqueue file
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

    //set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            install.setDataAndType(uri,
                    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
            startActivity(install);

            unregisterReceiver(this);
            finish();
        }
    };
    //register receiver for when .apk download is compete
    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

}

'''

All working fine except for

'''
public void download(View view) {
        String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        String fileName = "latest.apk";
        destination += fileName;
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

```
    //Delete update file if exists
    File file = new File(destination);
    if (file.exists())
        //file.delete() - test this, I think sometimes it doesnt work
        file.delete();



    //set downloadmanager
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://google.com/latest.apk"));


    //set destination
    request.setDestinationUri(uri);

    // get download service and enqueue file
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

    //set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            install.setDataAndType(uri,
                    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
            startActivity(install);

            unregisterReceiver(this);
            finish();
        }
    };
    //register receiver for when .apk download is compete
    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

}

'''

It download the latest.apk in /download folder and when try to install It show "error analysis package", but with a symple file manager I go to download and click on latest.apk Will be installed without any problem. So How I can fix It?

In manifest already added permission for install package, write on external and internal storage and internet.

Please help me, thanks

Comment: In my opinion, we have a solution that is more efficient for keeping users updated with the new releases. 
from in-app-updates https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates from the official documentation.

Comment: I need to update the app without Google play, because the app is not on market